# NTFS-3G mount problem with GPT / protective MBR

Tags: debian, mount, partition, hard-disk

I got some WD 10TB HDD's, initialized them in Windows 10 with an external USB3.0 adapter and formated them as NTFS / GPT.
Now i want to mount them in my Debian system, but, blkid does not show the UUID and cat /proc/partitions
does only show sdb.

```
cat /proc/partitions
8       16 9766436864 sdb

blkid /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: PTTYPE="PMBR"

gdisk -l /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 19532873728 sectors, 9.1 TiB
Model: WDC WD102KRYZ-01
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 28154B70-704B-4769-A0F9-AC8FF5C0F724
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 19532873694
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 19532873661 sectors (9.1 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

My other drive (sdc) looks like this

```
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
```

It seems that there is an issue with GPT. How can i fix this, to mount the drive properly?
I had this issue a year ago already with another drive, then i did clean the disk with diskpart within Windows 10 and re-initialised it, then the partition(s) did show up on my Debian system. The main problem now is, that the 10TB disks are already filled up with data...

Edit//

```
gdisk /dev/sdb

Expert command (? for help): o

Disk size is 19532873728 sectors (9.1 TiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:

Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1   4294967295   primary     0xEE
```

Edit 2//
wmic output

```
wmic partition get BlockSize, Name, Index, StartingOffset, Size

BlockSize  Index  Name
512        0      Disk #2, Partition #0  10000812474368  16777216
```

Comment: Post the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb`

Comment: I've added the output in my post above

Comment: Are you hiding your actual partitions? Your output is empty.

Comment: No there is no ouput, don't know why...

Comment: Please try opening this disk in Windows again. I'm quite sure you won't be able to open it because there are no partitions. Either you've erased them somehow or something similar has happened.

Comment: I have edited my main post... On Windows, there are two partitions, one main partition and another really small one (i think for the GPT?). When attaching the drive to my Windows system, i can access all my data without any problem

Comment: Windows always creates a system reserved as first partition. That is required before first NTFS partition if you have Windows installed. Not really required if not installing Windows. Is Windows fast start up on? That sets hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions and Linux NTFS driver will not normal r/w mount (you can manually mount read only) hibernated partitions to prevent damage. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: This is a data hdd only, no OS is installed there.

Answer (score 1):

> Please do the following:
>
> 1. `sudo gdisk /dev/sdb`
>
> 2. <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> - post the output

---

As far I can see Windows 10 has created an invalid GPT structure which neither the Linux kernel, not gdisk can recognize. Here's how you can try solving the issue.

Boot into Windows, run under the administrator cmd:

```
wmic partition get BlockSize, Name, Index, StartingOffset, Size
```

Write down/save all the partitions and offsets of the disk you're interested in.

Reboot into Linux and then using `fdisk` or `gdisk` recreate them. Then you'll be able to mount the disk. Mind that you can **potentially lose all your data** in a process. Proceed with extreme caution.

---

You might have created a dynamic disk in which case please consult with https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_disks

Comment: I've added the output in my first post

Comment: Will try that, thank you. How do i recreate them exactly by using fdisk or gdisk? I don't have much experience in using these two tools.

Comment: This shouldn't be too difficult. Compare the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and the `wmic` command I've already given. You can use `fdisk` to similarly recreate partions for `/dev/sdb`. If you're afraid, post the `wmic` output here and we'll tell you how to use `fdisk`.

Comment: I've posted the wmic output on my first post.

Comment: Are you sure it's **not** a **dynamic** disk? If it is, please use this howto: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_disks

Comment: I've checked it again, and it's not a dynamic disk.

Comment: Your wmic output is not ... normal. It says you have a single 16MB (!) partition at a 10TB offset. This doesn't look correct.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. When i plug it into my Windows machine with the USB3.0 adapter, it get's recognized without any issue.

Comment: I still believe it's a dynamic disk. How did you check it's basic, not dynamic?

Comment: I used the tool "testdisk" for that. Either way, is it possible to make the needed changes, so i can mount it on my debian at the end, or do i have to backup the whole 10TB of data and reformat it?

Comment: Please install `ldmtool` and check if `sudo ldmtool scan` shows something. I've no idea how `testdisk` works but it's not native to Windows, so I wouldn't trust its output too much.

Comment: The output ist empty -> []

Comment: Before backing up and re-partitioning please ask this question on https://superuser.com

Comment: Okay done, thank you for your time anyway :)
https://superuser.com/questions/1588240/ntfs-3g-mount-with-gpt-protective-mbr